# Trigger to Insert N number of default values into row

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sql-insert, database-trigger

So I have created the following Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER cascadeUserInsertionToRecommendations_tbl
    -> AFTER INSERT
    -> ON users_tbl FOR EACH ROW
    -> INSERT INTO recommendations_tbl(recommendation_userid, recommendation_category, recommendation_manufacturer) VALUES(NEW.user_id, 'diverse', 'diverse');
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.027 sec)
```

Actually I could have used the Default() instead of "diverse" on the other fields because "diverse" is actually the default value of these columns. But thats not the problem here.

In case I expand this table, I would very much appreciate if the above Trigger dynamically adapted to the new situation. 
Basically, the Trigger just needs to fill ALL the fields of the new row with the default value except for the one receiving the NEW.user_id.

I wondered if MySQL provided some syntax to accomplish this?

Comment: Isn't this the nth time you're asking a question about default values. Something is wrong with whatever you're trying to do. You never explained why you're doing this.

Comment: @Salman A I don't see your problem. SO asks us to ask distinct questions. If I try to be distinct, there's no way I could ask about a complex problem in just one question. Then the question would be overly broad or too convoluted. 

Also, SO requires us to remain simple in our questions. Therefore explaining my goals, unless necessary to answer the question, would be contradictory to this aim.

Comment: absolutely no problem. But your situation looks like an xy problem to me. You never explained the background, only the desired the goals. If I were to answer would ask you to keep NULLs in your data and replace them on the front end. E.g. the string `n/a` when the data is not available or `varias` for spanish variation of the application.

Comment: @SalmanA True, maybe keeping NULLs would work as well. But NULL is often handled differently by many APIs. Choosing a default string to substitute NULL Values eliminates this problem before it even comes up. 
But even more important is that my Default values represent the "highest" abstraction level in my representation of product attributes. All products belong into the "diverse" category, and inside diverse there are first computer, books etc. categories containing desktop, mobile or hardcover, softcover and so on. That's why I established a DEFAULT across the product related tables.

Comment: 'In case I expand this table' -  I take you mean add columns, 'I wondered if MySQL provided some syntax to accomplish this' no it doesn't and you cannot call dynamic sql from a trigger. So you have to have manual change control in place.

Comment: @P.Salmon Whatever, GMB answer worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Basically, the Trigger just needs to fill ALL the fields of the new row with the default value except for the one receiving the `NEW.user_id`.

Assuming that you properly defined default values for each column excepted `recommendation_userid`, all you have to do is not pass these additional columns when inserting. MySQL will automatically assign the default value to the columns that you did not provide when inserting.

So your `INSERT` command should just look like:

```
insert into recommendations_tbl(recommendation_userid) values(EW.user_id);
```

This will continue to work even if new columns are created in the target table (again, assuming that these new columns have a properly defined default value).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b820903d65c90e0214ec1cac8a895bc)**:

```
-- create the table with default values for all columns excepted the primary key
create table recommendations_tbl (
    recommendation_userid integer primary key, 
    recommendation_category varchar(10) default 'diverse',
    recommendation_manufacturer varchar(10) default 'diverse'
);


-- insert a record, providing the primary key only
insert into recommendations_tbl(recommendation_userid) values(1);

-- other columns were assigned default values
select * from recommendations_tbl;

recommendation_userid | recommendation_category | recommendation_manufacturer
--------------------: | :---------------------- | :--------------------------
                    1 | diverse                 | diverse
```